# How to load json images and text dynamically in Horizontal Scrollview in android?

Tags: android, json

i have an xml which contains an image and textview inside a relative layout in a horizontal ScrollView...how can i load images and texts which come from server into the horizontal scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relative1"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                         >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                             />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_wheels"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text=" Text" />
                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i get images and text from json i need to populate them in the horizontal scroll view...i searched a lot in google but couldn't come up with a solution..please help!

Comment: I don't know what the problem are you facing of .. !! Just set the bitmap of the image to the ImageView and text to the TextView and then findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1).requestLayout() to refresh the horizontal scrollview

Comment: the number of images and text's from json is not known before...in that case how can i load them one image into an imageview..could you please tell me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your xml... what you need to do is create the RelativeLayouts inside LinearLayout dynamically..the no. of RelativeLayout is equal to size of your json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <!--<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                     >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                         />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_wheels"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text=" Text" />
                </RelativeLayout>-->


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

suppose your json is like
[{"image":"","text":""},{"image":"","text":""},{"image":"","text":""},....]

```
JsonArray jsonArray=new JsonArray(<json>);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this); //create imageview dynamically
imgView.setImageBitmap(<image bitmap>);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);//create textview dynamically
textView.setText(<text>);

RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;
lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1;
lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp1.setMargins(0,0,10,0);
rl.setLayoutParams(lp1);
imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);

rl.addView(imgView,);//add imageview to relativelayout
rl.addView(textView);//add textview to relativelayout
indViewById(R.id.linearLayout).addView(rl);//now finally add this relativelayout to linearLayout of horizontall scrollview
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    return null;
}
}
```

> Note: - i haven't tested the code from myside.but the logic is same.

Comment: Thanku for the answer..i'm new to android can you please tell me how to create a relative layout dynamically and add to linear layout..can you please give an example code

Comment: got it thanku...but i wanted to add gap between the relative layouts in the linear layout how can i do that...i wanted a gap of 10dp between the 2 relative layouts...appreciate help!

Comment: i've updated the anser....setMargin() to relativelayout params will do so....and if this answer help..then accept the answer...

Comment: accepted the answer..could you please tell me how can i convert an image url to image...i am getting the images in the form of url's...please do me this last help i'd be greatful